# MirageSQLにて一覧の長さは１以上の条件どうやて判定する？

Tags: java, sql

MirageSQLで、SQLスクリプト内にWHERE-IN文で検索を付けたいと、渡したの変数はデータがあるかどうかの判定はどうやって指定しますか？

Java側で情報の洗い出すかのうですが、SQL内の判定ないでしょうか？

利用MirageSQLのバージョン：

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>jp.sf.amateras.mirage</groupId>
  <artifactId>mirage</artifactId>
  <version>1.2.0</version>
</dependency>
```

SQLでの判定文：

```
/*IF employeeList != NULL*/
    AND employeeId IN /*employeeList*/('101001')
/*END*/
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[official wiki](https://github.com/mirage-sql/mirage/wiki/2WaySQL#3if-else-end):

> `IF` conditions are written as [OGNL](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-ognl/) expressions.

とのことで、概ね一般的なJavaと同じように書けるかと思います。

```
/*IF !employeeList.isEmpty()*/
    AND employeeId IN /*employeeList*/('101001')
/*END*/
```